# Theano subtraction when you can't tile

Tags: theano

Say we have a theano matrix X that is nxm, and another one u that is nx1.  We want to do `X-u`, but if we do that we'll get an input dimension mismatch.  We could try tiling u, but tile only accepts constants and not variables.  How do we do this?

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

X, u = T.dmatrices("X", "u")
T.addbroadcast(u, 1)
r = X - u
f = theano.function([X, u], r)
f([[1], [0]], [[1]])
```

I then get the error `('Bad input argument to theano function with name "<stdin>:1"  at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 2, got 1 with shape (2,).')`

Comment: Check out `u.broadcastable`. You will find that in your code it is actually not. This is because `T.` operations never modify inplace, but return a new graph node. So you have to write `u = T.addbroadcast(u, 1)`. I updated my answer.

Comment: The "wrong number of dimensions" error doesn't seem to tally with the code. Are you sure you get that error message when you run that code?

Comment: might be an artifact of the edit

Comment: I know what was wrong now.  dmatrices can't be broadcast, so you have to change u to be a dcol..

Comment: You are right that `T.?matrix` doesn't broadcast by default, but the only problem with the code you are showing is that you didn't apply `T.addbroadcast` properly, otherwise it would work. So saying "dmatrices can't be broadcast" is a little misleading. I'd suggest you correct your example and add an extra way of doing it using dcol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X - u` should work exactly as you write it by broadcasting:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

n = 10
m = 20

X = T.arange(n * m).reshape((n, m))
u = T.arange(0, n * m, m).reshape((n, 1))

r = X - u

r.eval()
```

Similar to your updated question, you can do

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

X = T.dmatrix()
u = T.addbroadcast(T.dmatrix(), 1)

r = X - u

f = theano.function([X, u], r)

XX = np.arange(20.).reshape(2, 10)
uu = np.array([1., 100.]).reshape(2, 1)

f(XX, uu)
```